# How to deal with D3D12 live object caused by IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer?

Tags: directx12, dxgi

I get D3D12 WARNING if IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer is called. I know that this incurs increase in ref count of swap chain, and the resource pointer retrieved by GetBuffer is not supposed to be manually released unless IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers will be called. If the resource is released manually, SwapChain->Release() crashes at clean up.

Following is the D3D12 WARNING messages.

```
D3D12 WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING: Live Producer at 0x0000015934682578, Refcount: 10. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x0000015934812870, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00000159345B91E0, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00000159345B9930, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x0000015934844730, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x0000015934844480, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593462E760, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x0000015934845420, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D1B5750, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D34D330, Refcount: 6. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D436630, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D4978D0, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D4FD330, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D436880, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D329400, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D282BD0, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D3CBF60, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D3B70A0, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D372910, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D3CC3C0, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D434CC0, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D328C80, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D327B00, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x000001593D291C30, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D12 WARNING: Live                         Object :     23 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
DXGI WARNING: Live Producer at 0x0000015931BDA828, Refcount: 5. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x000001593D32AF40, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x000001593D3D4600, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x000001593D3A0390, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING: Live                         Object :      3 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
```

I've checked that device, command queue, and swap chain does not return ref count of 0 during clean up. However, releasing multiple times manually does not make sense.

I've tried,

- [Reordering of clean up.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215106/dx12-even-though-they-are-comptr-live-objects-apears-when-process-terminated)
- Manual release of multiple times (crashes when ref count 1 -> 0)
- Using ComPtr
- Binding descriptor heap having null RTVs (suspected render target being bound to pipeline)

None of them could remove the warning. The only thing for sure is that IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer is not called and command list recording is removed, the warning message does not occur. Anyone who has faced and fixed this issue helps, it will be really appreciated.

For further information, following is result of ReportLiveDeviceObjects with D3D12_RLDO_DETAIL just before releasing device object.

```
D3D12 WARNING: Live ID3D12Device at 0x000001C964F8C768, Refcount: 12 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #274: LIVE_DEVICE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12RootSignature at 0x000001C96512FA50, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #577: LIVE_ROOTSIGNATURE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12PipelineState at 0x000001C964ECD730, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #572: LIVE_PIPELINESTATE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12PipelineState at 0x000001C964ECB9F0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #572: LIVE_PIPELINESTATE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Resource at 0x000001C96515D150, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #575: LIVE_RESOURCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Heap at 0x000001C96DA52CD0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #579: LIVE_HEAP]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001C964F46290, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandQueue at 0x000001C96515D5B0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #570: LIVE_COMMANDQUEUE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001C96DAB6990, Name: Internal D3D12 Debug Fence, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandQueue at 0x000001C96DCBDD20, Refcount: 6, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #570: LIVE_COMMANDQUEUE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001C96DD08000, Name: Internal D3D12 Debug Fence, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live IDXGISwapChain at 0x000001C96DCDAF60, Refcount: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #275: LIVE_SWAPCHAIN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12LifetimeTracker at 0x000001C96DC934E0, Refcount: 2, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #1164: LIVE_LIFETIMETRACKER]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001C96DD05D50, Name: Internal DXGI Fence, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandAllocator at 0x000001C96DBF9C10, Name: Internal DXGI CommandAllocator, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #571: LIVE_COMMANDALLOCATOR]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12GraphicsCommandList at 0x000001C96DB81E90, Name: Internal DXGI CommandList, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #573: LIVE_COMMANDLIST12]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Resource at 0x000001C96DB310C0, Refcount: 2, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #575: LIVE_RESOURCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Heap at 0x000001C96DFA26F0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #579: LIVE_HEAP]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Resource at 0x000001C96DF23AF0, Refcount: 2, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #575: LIVE_RESOURCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Heap at 0x000001C96DFA29A0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #579: LIVE_HEAP]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001C96DD06690, Refcount: 2, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandAllocator at 0x000001C96E1AAF60, Name: Internal DXGI CommandAllocator, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #571: LIVE_COMMANDALLOCATOR]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandAllocator at 0x000001C96E1AA7E0, Name: Internal DXGI CommandAllocator, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #571: LIVE_COMMANDALLOCATOR]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12GraphicsCommandList at 0x000001C96DB86EB0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #573: LIVE_COMMANDLIST12]
```

ReportLiveDeviceObjects with D3D12_RLDO_IGNORE_INTERNAL.

```
D3D12 WARNING: Live ID3D12Device at 0x000001CD1238C768, Refcount: 12 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #274: LIVE_DEVICE]
```